# How to make Enums scalable?

Tags: solidity, enum, data

Let's say that I have a contract `Games.sol` containing an enum with multiple games.

`enum { TicTacToe, PacMan, Chess }`

This enum is currently imported from a library and I think that it's immutable, so how to scale this enum and add a game to it in the future ?

Thanks !